# Binding 'style' to a computed property

Tags: ember.js

I have a component which is inserted into the DOM as a '' tag (e.g., default behaviour). The component's job is to wrap a 3rd party jQuery tool and I'm trying to ensure it is responsive to "resize" events so I would like to explicitly set *width* and *height* style attributes.

In the component, it is easy enough to being to the style attribute:

```
attributeBindings: ['style'],
style: function() {
    return "width: auto";
}.property('widthCalc'),
```

In this case, this works but doesn't do anything useful because style just returns a static string (`width: auto`).

Instead what I want to do is -- based on any change to the computed property `widthCalc` -- set the width based on the new value. So here's the next logical step:

```
style: function() {
    var width = $('body')[0].offsetWidth;
    return 'width: ' + width + 'px';
}.property('widthCalc'),
```

This too works, dynamically setting the DIV to the width of the body's width (note: this isn't really what I want but it does prove that this simple binding works). Now what I really want is to get the value of width from a computed property on the component but I don't even have to go that far to run into trouble; notice that instead of a global jQuery selector I switch to a localised component-scoped selector:

```
style: function() {
    var width = this.$().offsetWidth;
    return 'width: ' + width + 'px';
}.property('widthCalc'),
```

Unfortunately this causes the page NOT to load and gives the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Something you did caused a view to re-render after it rendered but before it was inserted into the DOM.

I imagine this is Ember run-loop juju but I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to wrap the code in `Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', function(){});` From the docs: "afterRender meant to be run after all previously scheduled render tasks are complete. This is often good for 3rd-party DOM manipulation libraries, that should only be run after an entire tree of DOM has been updated"

Comment: Yeah I am using `schedule` in a few places but where would you put it? in the **style** computed property or the **widthCalc** property? I guess I can try both but I'm a bit surprised that computed properties aren't handled automatically by Ember.

Comment: I'm actually wondering if I need to wrap the scheduling in a RSVP promise too ... considering the computed property needs a synchronous return call I think.

Comment: @ken basically you cannot call `this.$()` if the component has not been added to the dom.

Comment: @ken Yeah as @melc said you cannot call `this.$()` if the component has not been added to the dom. So to make sure wherever you have `this.$()` try to wrap it in the `afterRender`.

Comment: Well this may be not knowing but I would say that at the point that the `didInsertElement` is called the component **would** be in the DOM, it's visibility, however, is the variable condition.

Comment: @ken is this http://emberjs.jsbin.com/delexoqize/1/edit?html,js,output what you describe? would something like this work for your case?

Comment: @ken or a bit more elegantly maybe something like http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hilalapoce/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @melc do you want to write up your solution as an answer so I can give you credit? In parallel I came up with a variant solution which solved the problem too. I'll post my solution too in case its useful to readers but I think your answer more directly answers the question I was asking above so I'll mark yours as correct.

Comment: @melc I liked your solution on paper but in all my tests it just wasn't throwing an exception. I found your support very helpful though. Have a look at the answer I post and see if you have anything to add to it.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not possible to call `this.$()` in the component before it has been added to the dom, provide an initial value until the component is ready. 
For example,

Setting a default value to the property `style` and on `didInsertElement` event reopen the class and define `style` as a calculated property using `this.$()`

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/delexoqize/1/edit?html,js,output

**js**

```
App.MyCompComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  attributeBindings:["style"],
  style:"visibility:hidden",
  prop1:null,
  initializeThisStyle:function(){
    this.set("style","visibility:visible");
    this.reopen({
      style:function(){
//          var thisOffsetWidth = this.$().get(0).offsetWidth;
        return "visibility:visible;color:red;background-color:lightgrey;width:"+this.get("prop1")+"px";
      }.property("prop1")
    });
  }.on("didInsertElement")
});
```

Alternatively handle the error raised by `this.$()` and provide a default value. Afterwards when the component will be added the property will be calculated as planned.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hilalapoce/1/edit?html,js,output

**js**

```
App.MyCompComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  attributeBindings:["style"],
  style:function(){
    try{
      this.$();//this will throw an erro initialy 

        return "visibility:visible;color:red;background-color:lightgrey;width:"+this.get("prop1")+"px";
    }catch(e){
      return "color:blue";
    }
  }.property("prop1"),
  prop1:null
});
```

Comment: I think the problem with this solution is that `didInsertElement` is triggered when the UI widget is painted into the DOM but at this stage it is *not* visible. It's only later, through a user event, makes this part of the DOM visible that the component needs to take action.

Answer (score 1):

With the component I was trying to solve for I ended coming up with an solution that seems effective to me which I will share below. For an understanding of the why I was getting the error and how one might more directly address that error please see the comment from @melc above.

### My Solution

What I'm solving for is resizing a jQuery component wrapped in an Ember component. In many cases, resizing is handled gracefully by CSS alone but some jQuery components -- including the very nice [knob](http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/) component from [aterrien](https://github.com/aterrien) -- has JS which gets directly involved and therefore needs the containers width and height properties to be set explicitly by the Ember component so that it reacts appropriately.

When solving for this I realised my use-case had two problems:

1. Solving for a page resize event
2. Adjusting to the fact that my *knob component* was -- at times -- in the DOM but in a part of the DOM which was not visible (more explicitly it was in Bootstrap tab which wasn't visible).

#### The Resize Listener

The first part of the solution is to listen for a page-level resize of the page. I do this with the following:

```
resizeListener: function() {
    var self = this;
    self.$(window).on('resize', Ember.run.bind(self, self.resizeDidHappen));
}.on('didInsertElement'),
```

#### Page Resize Handler

When a resize is done at the "page" level I now want my component to inspect what the resize impact has been on the component:

```
resizeDidHappen: function() {
    Ember.run.debounce(this, function() {
        // get dimensions
        var newWidth = Number(this.$().parent().get(0).offsetWidth);
        var newHeight = Number(this.$().parent().get(0).offsetHeight);
        // set instance variables
        this.set('width', newWidth);
        this.set('height', newWidth);
        // reconfigure knob
        this.$('.knob').trigger(
            'configure',
            {
                width: newWidth,
                height: newWidth
            }
        );                          
    }, 300);
}
```

This solves the page resize problem if it exists in isolation but to make the component it is probably a good idea to solve for the *visibility* use case as well (certainly in my case it was critical).

#### Visibility Handler

Why? Well, for two reasons that I can think of:

1. Many jQuery components refuse to load or perform badly if they aren't loaded
2. The ember component appears to not be able to establish a "resize" event when it is not visible in the DOM

The one problem is that there is no DOM-level event for visibility changes, so how do we react to a change in visibility without polling on an interval? Well in most cases there will be a UI element which is controlling the state of visibility. In my case it's Bootstrap's tab bar and in this case they have events that fire on the tabs when they become visible. Great. Here's a selector for Bootstrap's selector (assuming you're inside the content area of the newly visible tab):

```
visibilityEventEmitter: function(context) {
    // since there is no specific DOM event for a change in visibility we must rely on 
    // whatever component is creating this change to notify us via a bespoke event
    // this function is setup for a Bootstrap tab pane; for other event emmitters you will have to build your own   
    try {
        var thisTabPane = context.$().closest('.tab-pane').attr('id');
        var $emitter = context.$().closest('.tab-content').siblings('[role=tabpanel]').find('li a[aria-controls=' + thisTabPane + ']');
        return $emitter;
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('Problem getting event emitter: %o', e);
    }
    
    return false;
},
visibilityEventName: 'shown.bs.tab',
```

then we just need to add the following code:

```
_init: function() {
    var isVisible = this.$().get(0).offsetWidth > 0;
    if (isVisible) {
        this.visibilityDidHappen();
    }
}.on('didInsertElement'),
visibilityListener: function() {
    // Listen for visibility event and signal a resize when it happens
    // note: this listener is placed on a DOM element which is assumed 
    //       to always be visibile so no need to wait on placing this listener
    var self = this;
    Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', function() {
        var $selector = self.get('visibilityEventEmitter')(self);
        $selector.on(self.get('visibilityEventName'), Ember.run.bind(self, self.visibilityDidHappen ));         
    });
}.on('didInsertElement'),
visibilityDidHappen: function() {
    // On the first visibility event, the component must be initialised
    if(!this.get('isInitialised')) {
        this.initiateKnob();
    } else {            
        // force a resize assessment as window sizing may have changed 
        // since last time component was visible
        this.resizeDidHappen();
    }
},
```

Note that this also results in a tiny refactor of our resize listener, removing it's trigger from the `didInsertElement` event and instead being triggered by `initiateKnob` which will happen not when the Ember component loads but instead lazy load at the first point of visibility in the DOM.

```
initiateKnob: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.set('isInitialised', true);
    var options = this.buildOptions();
    this.$('.knob').knob(options);
    this.syncValue(); 
    this.resizeDidHappen(); // get dimensions initialised on load
    console.log('setting resize listener for %s', self.elementId);
    self.resizeListener(); // add a listener for future resize events
},
resizeListener: function() {
    this.$(window).on('resize', Ember.run.bind(this, this.resizeDidHappen));
},
```

### Does it work?

To a large degree but not completely. Here's what works:

- the first 'tab' which is visible at load resizes on demand
- all tabs resize when they are switched to (aka, when they gain visibility)

what doesn't work is:

- tabs other than the first tab do not resize (aka, the onresize callback appears broken)

The error I get is:

```
vendor.js:13693 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
      Backburner.run        vendor.js:13716 
      Backburner.join       vendor.js:34296 
      run.join          vendor.js:34349 
      run.bind          vendor.js:4759 
      jQuery.event.dispatch     vendor.js:4427 
      jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle
```

Not sure what to make of this ... any help would be appreciated. Full code can be found here:

https://gist.github.com/295e7e05c3f2ec92fb45.git

Comment: Thanks for sharing your valid solution to this problem. Can you please check if the gist is public or working, because i'm not able to access it. I'll also try to have a look at the issue you mention.

Comment: You're right it was private ... i've changed it to public now. Sorry for the mixup.